# How to extract documents from this whole corpus in R?

Tags: r

```
# 1
preliminari report intern algebra languag cacm decemb 1958 perli a
j samelson k ca581203 jb march 22 1978 8 28
pm 100 5 1 123 5 1 164 5 1
1 5 1 1 5 1 1 5 1 205
5 1 210 5 1 214 5 1 1982 5
1 398 5 1 642 5 1 669 5 1
1 6 1 1 6 1 1 6 1 1
6 1 1 6 1 1 6 1 1 6
1 1 6 1 1 6 1 1 6 1
165 6 1 196 6 1 196 6 1 1273
6 1 1883 6 1 324 6 1 43 6
1 53 6 1 91 6 1 410 6 1
3184 6 1 
# 2
extract of root by repeat subtract for digit comput cacm
decemb 1958 sugai i ca581202 jb march 22 1978 8
29 pm 2 5 2 2 5 2 2 5
2 
# 3
techniqu depart on matrix program scheme cacm decemb 1958 friedman
m d ca581201 jb march 22 1978 8 30 pm
3 5 3 3 5 3 3 5 3 
# 4
glossari of comput engin and program terminolog cacm novemb 1958
ca581103 jb march 22 1978 8 32 pm 4 5
4 4 5 4 4 5 4 
# 5
two squar root approxim cacm novemb 1958 wadei w g
ca581102 jb march 22 1978 8 33 pm 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
# 6
the us of comput in inspect procedur cacm novemb 1958
muller m e ca581101 jb march 22 1978 8 33
pm 6 5 6 6 5 6 6 5 6
477 5 6 6 6 6 
# 7
glossari of comput engin and program terminolog cacm octob 1958
ca581003 jb march 22 1978 8 35 pm 7 5
7 7 5 7 7 5 7 
# 8
on the equival and transform of program scheme cacm octob
1958 friedman m d ca581002 jb march 22 1978 8
36 pm 8 5 8 8 5 8 8 5
8 
# 9
propos for a...
```

I have this corpus with approximately 3000 documents to be retrieved. I want to create a new folder where I can keep these documents such as 1.txt, 2.txt and so on. Each document will begin with a #. For example, 1.txt will contain everything starting from # 1 till # 2, 2.txt will contain everything starting from # 2 till # 3 and so on.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The numbers in the bold letters were actually #1, #2, #3, #4, and so on. I don't know how it got converted to bold and my hash disappeared when I posted this question :/

Comment: Also, the corpus is in .txt file.

Comment: Please try to re-format your question so it is easier to read. Plus provide us with a clear question and what you have done to date

Comment: I've edited to try and reformat the text. If it looks wrong, please comment.

Comment: It looks the way how I wanted to post this question. Thank you for reformatting the text @Spacedman :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your corpus is in a file called `corpus.txt` which looks like this:

```
# 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
# 2
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
# 3
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

You can import the data using `readLines`, then extract the indices of the elements starting with `#`. Then you split the text file according to those indices and generate the separate text files in a loop.

Example:

```
## Import corpus:
textVec <- readLines("corpus.txt")

## Find indices of the lines starting with '#':
indexVec <- c(grep("^#", textVec), length(textVec) + 1)

## Split corpus:
textList <- lapply(1:(length(indexVec) - 1), 
    function(ii) textVec[(indexVec[ii]+1):(indexVec[ii+1] - 1)])

## Generate text files:
for (ii in seq(along = textList)) writeLines(textList[[ii]], con = paste0(ii, ".txt"))
```